# AttributeError as I try to run a simple loadtest with locust

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

I have created a simple load test file for redis, but as I am trying to execute the file as :

```
locust -f load-test.py
```

I get an error saying `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_catch_exceptions'`. I cannot understand the reason for this. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Here is the little code, that I wrote.

```
# Reference 
# https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html
# https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py

from locust import Locust, TaskSet, task
import redis


class LoadTestTasks(TaskSet):

    def __init__(self, args):
        self.redis = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379)

    @task
    def update_total_requests(self):
        if self.redis.exists("total-calls") == 1:
            self.redis.incr("total-calls")
        else:
            self.redis.set("total-calls", 1)


class Connection(Locust):
    task_set = LoadTestTasks
    min_wait = 500
    max_wait = 700
```

The stack error:

```
    <Greenlet at 0x109f01ae8: start_locust(<class 'load-test.Connection'>)> failed with AttributeError
[2019-09-20 15:11:26,551] my-PCs-MacBook-Pro.local/ERROR/stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[2019-09-20 15:11:26,551] my-PCs-MacBook-Pro.local/ERROR/stderr: 
[2019-09-20 15:11:26,551] my-PCs-MacBook-Pro.local/ERROR/stderr: File "/Users/my-pc/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/locust/core.py", line 354, in run
    if self.locust.stop_timeout is not None and time() - self._time_start > self.locust.stop_timeout:
```

Comment: Add more details about the stack trace so we can trace where from the exception is coming.

Comment: @lucrib Have updated but I could not that very useful.

Comment: Your stack trace right now doesn't show the error you listed right now

Answer (score 1):

You have to add super call to `__init__` method of TaskSet otherwise your *TaskSet* is not initialised by Locust.

```py
...
class LoadTestTasks(TaskSet):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.redis = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379)
...
```